# same color scheme for 2 pie charts

Tags: visualization, matplotlib

I want to visualize statistics from two large dataframes with similar data in two pie charts. I would like for these two charts to use the same color when the same category appears in the chart. I have found similar questions online but all the advice include manually creating a dictionary of categories, which seems to be too complicated because of the large number of categories I have in the dataset.